# @Input() with null values on Angular 9 after update from 6.1

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

Something change in @Input() usage on child components? Some of my child components get the values null, but if a put IvyCompiler: false they start to work again and receive values normally.
I read this on the docs, but for me isn't clear what change for @Input() and the usage on child components:

> Unbound inputs for directives (e.g. name in ) are now
>   set upon creation of the view, before change detection runs
>   (previously, all inputs were set during change detection).

https://angular.io/guide/ivy-compatibility#changes-you-may-see

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: @ionut-t is this ** @Input()  ** from Angular, nothing specific on the usage, the only difference is the application used to be angular 6.1 and now is 9.1.

Comment: @MikeOne I'm using just Input() in this components, 
I'm not using ViewChild.

Comment: Best would be to post code if you want help. Obviously people are still using `@Input` without an issue, so you are doing something out of the ordinary. Nevertheless, I guess your code depends on the order of the `@Input` being defined in your template, and that your read this value from a setter on another `@Input`. With ivy this order has changed to the order it is defined in the parent template. Pre-ivy the order was defined by the order of the inputs in the component itself. If this is the case you should change your code, this is undefined behavior and your code should not depend on it

Comment: @PoulKruijt I tried to reproduce this https://stackblitz.com/edit/input-error? 
it's exactly like my code, the only thing different is that I created the project with version 9.1 on stackbliz. And my project came from version 6.1 and is now in version 9.1.
The error does not happen in the version that comes from 9.1

Answer (score 3):

Like I already mentioned in my component. Your component's inputs are depending on each other in the setter. For instance, you have this piece of code:

```
@Input()
set show(show: boolean) {
  if (show === true && this.action === "update") {
    this.exchange();
  }
  this._show = show;
}
```

There is actually a specific order in which inputs get set at component creation. I can't remember which belongs to which version, but they did change this behavior with ivy. So either it depends on the order in which you define it in the parent template, or it depends on the order in which inputs are defined in the component itself.

But like i mentioned before, your code should not depend on this behavior, and you should move this logic to the `ngOnChanges` hook. This hook will be called first, even before the `ngOnInit`. In here you can be sure that all the inputs that are defined in the parent template are set. That would change your code to:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
  // here both `show` and `action` input will be set at the first `ngOnChanges` call  
  if (changes.show && this.show && this.action === 'update') {
    this.exchange();
  }
}
```

Be aware though that this will only get called when the `show` input changes externally, not from within the component itself. For this you need to change your components logic to manually check for what the action is and call `exchange()`

Comment: I believe this changed in Angular 9, since I ran into this issue when upgrading from 8 -> 9

Comment: @RMorrisey you are correct. That's because ivy is default turned on in angular 9